# System navigation bar color is grey when set to transparent using SystemChrome

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I used his command to try and make the system navigation bar transparent:

```
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent));
```

the status bar appears transparent as intended but the navigation bar appears in grey color

I am using a pixel 3 emulator with android 10 (API 29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to hide bottomNavigation

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

Comment: I don't want to hide it, just make the color transparent so the buttons blend in with background @Diwyansh